# 《庄子》人间世篇名读音及其解释讨论(Zhuangzi discussion)

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronunciation

《庄子》内七篇，曰：逍遥游、齐物论、养生主、人间世、德充符、大宗师、应帝王。

吾见今主流皆解人间世篇名作人间社会，而亦有异见作人处社会解，甚以为然。

庄子善寓言、重言、卮言。人间世多假人口而述己，略可剖为：颜回请行孔子，叶公子高使齐语孔子，颜阖傅太子而问蘧伯玉，匠石不顾栎社，南伯子綦异大木，孔子适楚遇接舆 等章。

纵观南华，庄子喻人以处己，而非论世以砭弊，故也人间世作人处世，读去声，明矣。

提问（Question）：

就此话题而言，少有资料论述。但求有关文献或途说，体裁不限。谢谢大家╰(*´︶`*)╯

Comment: Edited. Now I clearly state I want any form of documentation or hearsay.

Comment: 古調今人安知， 解「人間世 」為「人間，人世」 可也，解 「人間世」為「人居於世」亦可也。 觀其內容，兩說皆合，究亦無果

Comment: Please be more specific about what your question is. I find it overly broad, if not confusing.

Answer (score 1):

百度 [庄子·内篇·人间世](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BA%BA%E9%97%B4%E4%B8%96/2110596?fromtitle=%E5%BA%84%E5%AD%90%C2%B7%E5%86%85%E7%AF%87%C2%B7%E4%BA%BA%E9%97%B4%E4%B8%96&fromid=10162802)

> *《人间世》是一篇《庄子》内篇中的文章。本书的中心是讨论**处世之道**，既表述了庄子所主张的**处人与自处**的人生态度，也揭示出庄子处世的哲学观点。*

根据百度对该文章的介绍「间」解作动词「居于」似乎十分合理，另一方面， 将「人间世」解作名词即 ，「人类社会」也不算违背文章的内容。硏究人类社会，就是硏究人与人的互动与交流，而叙述人在世间也是叙述人与人的互动与交流

可能庄子将该篇定名为「人间世」本来就知道这篇题含有双重意，平常说话也常见有语带相关言词，玩文字游戏时就更加普遍。